# query for extracting values from a column containing data in XML format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-analyzer

suppose I have a table, **mydata**, that has a column ***xmldata*** whose values are text in XML format such as

```
<maindataheading>
    <firstleveldata>
        <pricedata pricetype="normal">123</pricedata>
    </firstleveldata>
</maindataheading>
```

how do I extract `<pricedata pricetype="normal">123</pricedata>` from the xmldata column?

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample SQL for retrieving a varchar value from XML:

```
DECLARE @MyXmlData XML

-- Read XML data into variable
 SELECT @MyXmlData = xmldata
   FROM MyData

-- Check if the XML node exists before attempting to retrieve it
IF @MyXmlData.exist('/maindataheading/firstleveldata/pricedata') = 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyDataValue VARCHAR(255)

    -- Get specific XML data
     SELECT @MyDataValue = ParamValues.ID.Value('.', 'varchar(255)')
       FROM @MyXmlData.nodes('/maindataheading/firstleveldata/pricedata') AS ParamValues(ID)

    IF @MyDataValue IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Do something with data
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select xmldata.query('/maindataheading/firstleveldata/pricedata')
from mydata
```

Result:

```xml
<pricedata pricetype="normal">123</pricedata>
```